# Create 3D polygon from 3D point map

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, 3d

I'm a new qGis user (just started yesterday) and I'm trying to find a solution to a problem.
I need to generate a 3D polygon starting from a list of points located in space, with X and Y coordinates and elevation value (these points are generated by a telemeter, used to map a landslide areas like mountains and hills).

I tried the Contour tool but it works only when I have just 4 points on my list (so that it says 2x2 grid). When I add more points it says "No regular grid" and clicking OK crashes qGis.
I also tried some Vector tools but all I can get is 2D polygons or a polygon with fixed altitude, not a polygon where every vertex has its own altitude.

Two images to explain the concept:

My 3D points:
[image: 3d points]

What it should look like when having a lot of points:

https://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-white-abstract-polygonal-mountain-d-illustration-isolated-on-white-563125678.jpg

Is there a way to do it on QGIS?